# Get last selected Spinner value before change

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner and I want to get the last selected value of it when I click on the spinner (basically just before the items in the list are being shown).

How can I achieve this?

Update:
Example: There are a dynamic amount of spinners. User clicks in spinner 1 and selects a value, let's say "house". Then clicks somewhere else. Then clicks in spinner 1 again. What I now need is to return the value "house" that was previously was selected before the user selects a different value i.e. "car" in that spinner. I can not use the local storage to save that value beforehand because it's going to be a dynamic amount of spinners to be added.

And yes, I did in fact read the documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html already but what I need isn't explained there.

Comment: Have you tried anything in particular yet?

Comment: I've tried an OnClickListener which crashed. I tried OnClick also, same problem. I'm already using the setOnItemSelectedListener() but that will give me the newly selected value back and not the previous valueb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution is to add a TextView widget with each added Spinner. Set the TextView to "gone" (not visible). When the spinner changes set the value to that TextView. This way you can store the last selected spinner value in the TextView. When the user clicks on the spinner and changes the value you can still access the previously selected/unselected value from the spinner through the TextView widget.

```
// Use this TextView to temporarily store the spinner value
final TextView hiddenTextView = new TextView(getContext());
hiddenTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getContext());
spinner.setPrompt(getString(R.string.email_other));

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), R.array.email_types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

            Log.d(TAG, "TextView Value before spinner change: " + hiddenTextView.getText());

            String spinnerValue = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());

            hiddenTextView.setText(spinnerValue);
            Log.d(TAG, "TextView Value after spinner change: " + hiddenTextView.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            return;
        }

    });
```

Comment: you dont have to declare another `View` for that, i think `setTag()` method of the `View` class is for this purpose.

you can simply add that text/object to spinner view using `setTag()` and get that text using `getTag()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can declare a String array and then use it to storage the items values. Showing this in a TextView is a way to see if it works.

Something like this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    selection.setText(items[arg2]);

}
```

I already have faced a similar situation, but I don't remember exactly how I solved it. Tell me if it gives a better idea to you, I'm new participating here.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. It didn't work with the string array. However, I figured a way how to make it work. Will answer my own question.

Answer (score -1):

```
Spinner mySpinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner);
String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

> When the user selects an item from the drop-down, the Spinner object
>   receives an on-item-selected event.
>
> To define the selection event handler for a spinner, implement the
>   AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener interface and the corresponding
>   onItemSelected() callback method. For example, here's an
>   implementation of the interface in an Activity:
>
> ```
> public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
>     ...
>
>     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
>             int pos, long id) {
>         // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
>         // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
>     }
>
>     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
>         // Another interface callback
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener requires the onItemSelected()
>   and onNothingSelected() callback methods.
>
> Then you need to specify the interface implementation by calling
>   setOnItemSelectedListener():
>
> ```
> Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
> spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
> ```

### IN YOUR CASE:

TO se if the user clicked on the spinner, do this:

```
     if (spin.getSelectedItemPosition() < 0) {
    Spinner mySpinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner);
    String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

}
```

This means user clicked the spinner, but not any items of it.

**EDIT AGAIN**

```
 public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
>         ...
>         
>         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
>                 int pos, long id) {
>              parent.getItemAtPosition(pos) //THIS GETS YOU THAT VALUE THAT THE USER CLICKED ON DYNAMICALLY
>         }
>     
>         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
>             // Another interface callback
>         }
>     }
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: I need to get the value right when I click on the spinner. Not before or at any other time. I already know that i can get the currently selected value like that.

Comment: @e-nature Alright, I have edited it to show you how to get when the user clicks the spinner. Let me know if it works in a comment

Comment: I undid the downvote, sorry ;) but it's not what I need. Let's say the user selected "House" from the spinner, and then later clicks on the same spinner again (there's a dynamic amount of spinners), I need to get that "House" value right then during the click on the spinner. The thing is I have a dynamic amount of spinners in a form (added progammatically) that will be added whenever the user clicks on "add email address".

Comment: hm now sure if I can follow you with your solution. Where would I have to add the `if (spin.getSelectedItemPosition() < 0) {...` exactly? I guess somewhere I probably need a OnClick() event or similar, no?

Comment: @e-nature Okay, I will edit again. Let me know if it works with your needs.

Comment: @e-nature I edited. Basically use `parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)` in `onItemSelected`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I just tried it in my code but it doesn't work the way I want. With this code it also returns the newly selected value in the spinner and not the previously selected (or rather unselected) value from the spinner.